# Python pyqtgraph how to set x and y axis limits on graph, no autorange

Tags: python, graph, plot, axis, pyqtgraph

I would like to know how I can set the x and y axis limits that are displayed for a pyqtgraph.GraphicsWindow.addPlot object. I need to display a lot of data inside a loop (hence using pyqtgraph) but I would rather preallocate my axes as opposed to allowing autorange to potentially enhance speed. As an example,

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="My plotting examples")
win.resize(1000,600)
win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Plotting')
p1 = win.addPlot(title="plot1")
p2 = win.addPlot(title="plot2")
curve1 = p1.plot(pen='y')
curve2 = p1.plot(pen='r')
curve3 = p2.plot(pen='b')
x = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
x_current = x[0]
p1.setXRange((5,20), padding=0)
for i in range(1,len(x)):
    x_current = np.append(x_current,x[i])
    curve1.setData(x_current,np.sin(x_current))
    curve2.setData(x_current,np.cos(x_current))
    curve3.setData(x_current,np.tan(x_current))
    app.processEvents()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

The problem lies in the line `p1.setXRange((5,20),padding=0)`. This results in the error: TypeError: setXRange() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)

I think this should be a very simple question, just setting the axis ranges before plotting.

Answer (score 19):

As the error message indicates, you have not supplied the correct number of arguments to `setXRange()`. The correct line should look like:

```
p1.setXRange(5, 20, padding=0)
```

Documentation [here](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/viewbox.html#pyqtgraph.ViewBox.setXRange).

Comment: `padding=0` Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The questions asks how to set a limit to the view which none of the responses to this point answers. For others who come across this the view of the plot can be limited to a section of the axis like this:

```
p1.plotItem.vb.setLimits(xMin=a, xMax=b, yMin=c, yMax=d)
```

Documentation:
http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/viewbox.html

Answer (score 3):

Michael.

The easiest way would be to simply specify your ranges as elements of a list. Replace the `p1.setXRange` with something like this:

```
p1.setRange(xRange=[5,20])
```

And that's it!

Check the documentation of this class in:
http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/viewbox.html#pyqtgraph.ViewBox.setRange