# Set the X and Y range in pyqtgraph's ImageView

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

Is there any way to set the pyqtgraph ImageView X and Y range by code? By clicking right mouse button on ImageView in GUI program, there is an option to set the X and Y axis. However, in the Docs API Reference for [ImageView](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/widgets/imageview.html) there is no mention of how to set the X-Y range.

[image]

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29598442/python-pyqtgraph-how-to-set-x-and-y-axis-limits-on-graph-no-autorange

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`setLimits()`](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/viewbox.html#pyqtgraph.ViewBox.setLimits) to constrain the view range. You can set the minimum/maximum range for the x and y axis using `xMin`, `xMax`, `yMin`, and `yMax`

```
plot_widget = pg.PlotWidget()
plot_widget.setLimits(xMin=1, xMax=5, yMin=0, yMax=100)
```

For instance with

```
plot_widget.setLimits(xMin=0, xMax=.5, yMin=0, yMax=400)
```

[image]

and with

```
plot_widget.setLimits(xMin=.2, xMax=.3, yMin=0, yMax=125)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for advices. I found that ImageView doesn't have an option to set limits. To set limits for ImageView, it must be uses as PlotItem, example below

```
self.plot = pg.PlotItem()
imv = pg.ImageView(self.plot)
```

and now its possible to use setLimits, setXRange, setYRange or any other similar function to limit region.